# Scroll the exact element into view_selenium python

Tags: python, selenium, element

I use a python script to perform some actions on a website. One of the actions is to insert value and select the exact value from the list. The issue with the code below is that is selecting the first value that appears and not the exact value.
For example, I'm searching for 'algodón' and it should select the exact value available in the dropdown as 'Algodón' and not 'Mezcla de algodón'.

my code

```py
button = WebDriverWait(driver, 6).until(ec.element_to_be_clickable((By.CLASS_NAME,'awsui-select-dropdown-filter')))
driver.implicitly_wait(10)

ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(button).click(button).perform()
ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(button).send_keys(a).perform()

# ------------------click checkbox
element = driver.find_element_by_class_name('awsui-select-option-checkbox')
actions = ActionChains(driver)
actions.move_to_element(element).perform()
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", element)
element.click()

bulk = WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(ec.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH,'//*[@id="awsui-tabs-0-FILTERED_QUESTIONS_TAB-panel"]/span/div/awsui-cards/div/div[2]/div[1]/span/span/div[1]/div/div/div[3]/awsui-button')))
ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(bulk).click(bulk).perform()
```

How this appears in the dropdown:

[image]

What should select:

[image]

Do you have any suggestion on how should I modify the code to select the exact match?

Comment: It could be helpful if you could provide the URL of the website.

Comment: We need to see the HTML for that option to help you further, Please share HTML or page url ?

Comment: Thank you for your answer, you will not have access to the website even if I share the link. However, each time I will access the site, there will be different options in the list, not sure how html would help here. I was hoping the issue is here driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", element) and this can be modified somehow to not take the first item in the list of not matches entirely.